# Generate a series of increasing numbers by a constant floating point value

Tags: c++, c++11, std

I know iota function, but it will just work integer values since it is calling ++ operator.

I want to generate increasing float numbers by lets say 0.5 like 
[0.5, 1, 1.5....], and insert them to my vector

The final solution I came up with is :

```
    double last = 0;
    std::generate(out , out + 10, [&]{
        return last += 0.5; 
    });
```

Which kind of works but I have to use a extra variable. Is there a std func that I am missing like the function "iota" in  "D language" example : `auto rf = iota(0.0, 0.5, 0.1);`

Comment: so do you want to **increase** the values in a vector, or to **generate** a series of increasing numbers?

Comment: Generate a series of increasing numbers, I edited the question I hope it is more understandable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your compiler supports C++ 2014 when you can write

```
double a[10];

std::generate( a, a + 10, 
              [step = 0.0] () mutable { return step += 0.5; } );

for ( double x : a ) std::cout << x << ' ';
std::cout << std::endl;
```

The output will be

```
0.5 1 1.5 2 2.5 3 3.5 4 4.5 5
```

That is you may use an init capture without declaring an extra variable in the scope where the lambda is defined.

Otherwise you can declare a static variable inside the lambda expression. For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main() 
{
    double a[10];

    std::generate( a, a + 10, 
                  [] () mutable ->double { static double value; return value += 0.5; } );

    for ( double x : a ) std::cout << x << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output will be the same

```
0.5 1 1.5 2 2.5 3 3.5 4 4.5 5
```

Comment: Thank a lot very elegant solution, only problem I have vs2012 :(

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am almost sure this is the best way but I am still hoping  for a better boost or std way. Also even globals (statics are also like globals and that is why I don't like the idea) always  initiliaze with 0, I think initiating the static variable still good idea.

Comment: @Kadir Erdem Static variables of fundamental types are zero initialized by the compiler. This static variable is alive only within the call of the algorithm because it is a static data member of the unnamed class that corresponds to the lambda.

Comment: I am just asking to learn. So , void foo () { static int i) and [](){static int i}; are different. Is there any link you know about "static data member of unnamed class" subject?

Comment: @Kadir Erdem Demir I think you should download the Working Draft of C++ Standard  from ISO site. LAmbda expressions are not functions. They are function objects that is they are defined as unnamed classes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79948/discussion-between-kadir-erdem-demir-and-vlad-from-moscow).

Comment: @Kadir Erdem Demir I will be absent about a half of hour.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) after `iota`:

```
iota(begin(a), end(a), 0);    
const auto op = bind(multiplies<double>(), placeholders::_1, .5);
transform(begin(a), end(a), begin(a), op);
```

alternatively using [`boost::counting_iterator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/iterator/doc/counting_iterator.html):

```
transform(boost::counting_iterator<int>(0),
          boost::counting_iterator<int>(n),
          begin(a),
          bind(multiplies<double>(), placeholders::_1, .5));
```

Comment: But what if the range is not like 1 to 10 but a float range like 0.0 to 0.5. Will it work ?

Comment: what do u mean? as long as you are incrementing by a constant this should work

Comment: Or with a lambda instead of bind: `auto op = [ ](double& a){ a *= 0.5; };`

Comment: @behzad.nouri what I meant was; lets say my range is : 0.0, 0.5 and I want to increment by 0.1 , so result will be 0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5